# How to group data again in a single object with new keys after a mongodb $group?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb database with a collection of companies that look like this (it's just a sample, the actual collection is much larger):

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 100,
    "name": "Test Name 1",
    "level": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 101,
    "name": "Test Name 2",
    "level": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 102,
    "name": "Test Name 3",
    "level": "2"
  }
]
```

Where "level" can only range from 0 to 5

I'm trying to make an aggregate query with $group and $project that counts how many companies there are in each level, but according to the API specification I need follow, it needs to be formatted like this, in a single object:

```js
{
  "metrics": {
    "companies": {
      "total": <integer>,
      "level1": <integer>,
      "level2": <integer>,
      "level3": <integer>,
      "level4": <integer>,
      "level5": <integer>
    }
  }
}
```

The closest I could get to this was using $group and $project like this:

```js
Companies.aggregate([{
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    level: "$level"
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                level: "$_id.level",
                total: "$count"
            }
        }
    ])
```

Which gives the following result:

```
[
  {
    "level": 3,
    "total": 108
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "total": 172
  },
  {
    "level": 2,
    "total": 624
  },
  {
    "level": 4,
    "total": 98
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "total": 137
  },
  {
    "level": 0,
    "total": 94
  }
]
```

However, this result is an array and I need to put the data for each level in a single object with new keys "level1", "level2", etc, according to the specification.

I believe I need to make another $group operation but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understand, but I suppose you just need to map it, like here:

```
> var aux = new Object;
> db.Companies.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        level: "$level"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      level: "$_id.level",
      total: "$count"
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(a){aux["level"+a.level] = a.total;});
> printjson(aux);
{ "level2" : 1, "level1" : 2 }
```

Comment: I was actually hoping I could get it directly from the aggregate query, without the need for a for loop, but this provides a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there could be better solution, but this one is working:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
$group:{_id:{level: "$level"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}, 
{$group:{"_id": 0, levels: {$push: {_id:"$_id.level", count: "$count"}}, total: {$sum: "$count"}}}, 
{$unwind: "$levels"}, 
{$sort: {"levels._id": 1}}, 
{$group:{_id: 0, levels: {$push: {levels:"$levels.count"}}, "total": {$avg:"$total"}}}, 
{$project: {total: "$total", level1: {$arrayElemAt: ["$levels",0]}, level2: {$arrayElemAt: ["$levels", 1]}, level3: {$arrayElemAt: ["$levels",2]}, level4: {$arrayElemAt: ["$levels",3]},level5: {$arrayElemAt: ["$levels",4]} }}, 
{$project: {_id: 0, metrics: {companies: {total: "$total", level1: "$level1.levels", level2: "$level2.levels", level3: "$level3.levels",level4: "$level4.levels", level5: "$level5.levels"}}}}
])
```

Returned result:

```
{ "metrics" : 
 { "companies" : 
    { "total" : 7, 
    "level1" : 1, 
    "level2" : 2, 
    "level3" : 2, 
    "level4" : 1, 
    "level5" : 1 
} } }
```